# Finding the stable branch for a system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For this system of differential equations, how can I find the stable branch?

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = y-x  , \frac{dy}{dt} = x$$

I know it has something to do with the eigenvalues being of opposite sign and then setting a constant equal to zero. I'm not sure how to put it all together.

Comment: I get the eigenvalues of -0.5- (√5)/2 and -0.5+ (√5)/2.  The stable branch is a line along which we tend to the saddle point as t tends to infinity.

Comment: The point (0,0) is the saddle point.

Comment: Are they y=x and x=0 which are found by setting the derivatives equal to 0?

Comment: Find stable eigenspace. Or solve the system and find constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ for which solution goes to origin as $t \rightarrow \infty$ -- the result will be the same.